# Intel i7 6700k cooler

Tags: cooling, processor

I am looking for a decent cooler for my i7 6700k. I have *not* bought the CPU yet. So, if there is a (not that great at terminology) ATX sized cooler that is ~<60 dollars, that would be great.

Unless, of course, the 6700k already has a stock cooler. Please only tell me if it has stock if you have bought it. I have read multiple sites saying it does and doesnt. Pictures would be awesome.

I'm not overclocking, and playing games like Minecraft, FSX, Kerbal Space Program, and Planet Coaster. Also, I use Sony Vegas Pro 14 for video editing and rendering.

Noise is not an issue for me since I'm using headphones.

Thanks!

Edit: thanks to commenters for suggestions.

Comment: @NZKshatriya IMO the 95xx series are the few CPUs that **do** need liquid cooling. Can't be much worse than gaming laptops though, I swear mine can only dissipate ~22 W XD. To OP: If you're not overclocking, you might want to look at the Xeon 12xx v5s as well. The base HT model is the 1230, and it should sell for not much more than an i5. They're normally clocked slightly lower, but you could save ~$50. Make sure to get a boxed one if you want the stock cooler, IIRC the OEM/Tray versions are shipped without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not looking to overclock or anything save yourself a few bucks and go with the I7-6700 Retail Box [I7-6700 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0136JONG8).

Fan verification based on model from [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/88196/Intel-Core-i7-6700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz#@specifications). It is said to include Thermal Solution - E973979. [Link for Picture](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Radiator-Intel-Original-CPU-PWM-Socket-1156-E97379-001/dp/B005M0NW1M)

If you decide you want to go with a i7-6700K you have two options

Fan cool it and never plan on overclocking us a [Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005O65JXI).

Water cool it with a [Corsair Hyrdo H60](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A0HZMGA) and give yourself flexibility on being able to overclock in the future and stay in your budget.

In the end, there is no need to spend the extra money on the "K" version of the CPU to begin with if you are not going to overclock

Comment: Agreed, and I have run an FX-6100 OCd to 4.2Ghz stable (just using FSB modifier) for ages, using same Hyper 212 EVO.....now....if only I could beef up the cooling on my i7 laptop (would have bought an AMD gaming laptop if someone would MAKE ONE

Comment: A big air cooler, à la NH-D14, would likely perform better than an AiO with a tiny radiator. AiOs are more suited for good cooling in a compact system IMO, or if you have a massive 200 W plus TDP (models with large radiators only. Do not attempt with Cosair H60).